# Got a value from multiple class

Tags: jquery

I see someone had same problem with me, but I don't know what's wrong when I try to implement it.

So when press the *show* button it should return a specific value from each column

Code :

```js
// find elements
$(".btn").click(function(){
 var line = $('.trData').siblings('tdData').val();
 alert(line);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<tbody>
<tr class = "trData">
  <td><input class="tdData" type=text value = 1>
    <button class="btn">Show</button>
  </td>
  <td><input class="tdData" type=text value = 2>
    <button class="btn">Show</button>
  </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Comment: Your `<tr class="trData">` element has no siblings. Try `$('.trData .tdData').each(function() { alert(this.value) })`

Comment: the `tdData` that had it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a few issues in your current code.

- `.trData` has no siblings. You need to get the sibling`.tdData` element from the `button` which was clicked. This can be done by using the `this` keyword in the handler function to refer to the element which raised the event.
- The `tdData` selector is missing the `.` prefix
- The HTML is missing the `<table>` element, although I assume this is just a typographical mistake in the question

With that said, try this:

```js
$(".btn").click(function() {
  var line = $(this).siblings('.tdData').val();
  console.log(line);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="trData" border="1">
      <td>
        <input class="tdData" type="text" value="1">
        <button class="btn">Show</button>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input class="tdData" type="text" value="2">
        <button class="btn">Show</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```